# Verifying the triangle inequality

Tags: inequality

I am going through some practice problems in Abbott's Analysis text, and one of them is the following: Verify the triangle inequality in the special case where

a) a and b have the same sign; 
b) $a \geq 0$, $b < 0$, and $a+b \geq 0$.

I do not know where to begin because I don't know how exactly to go about the 'verification' given such conditions. Thanks!

Comment: Is it asking you to plug in specific values for $ a $ and $ b $ in each case or is it asking you to prove the formula works in each case given the conditions presented in each part?

Comment: @anon: I think it is asking me to prove that it works given the condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For instance, in case (a), you could distinguish between two possibilities:

1. $a,b \geq 0$. Then $a+b \geq 0 $ too and $\mid a+b\mid = a+b$ which is certainly equal to $\mid a \mid +\mid b\mid = a +b$.
2. $a,b \leq 0$. Then $a+b \leq 0$ too and $\mid a+b\mid = -(a+b)$ which is certainly equal to $\mid a \mid +\mid b\mid = -a -b$.

Comment: Oh so that's enough formalism? I think I was confused because it seemed so obvious that I didn't know how to write it down. Thanks!

Comment: @confused: Maybe if you're happy with my answer, you could mark it as "better" answer too in a couple of days (just to see if someone writes another one).